# How do I make box-shadow fully around element without any gradient?

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

Below is my code for a button. I want to use a box-shadow to create kind of a 2nd border of the buttons instead of having it wrapped inside something. The reason for this is to give me more options to change the look of this.

Right now I can either using something like `box-shadow: 0 0 5px #EEE;` or `box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 #EEE, -5px -5px 0 #EEE;` to create the kind of 2nd border.

Except with the first one there is of course a gradient and the second one there is a gap on bottom left and top right. How do I create no gap or no gradient for the effect I want?

```
button {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEE);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 #EEE, -5px -5px #EEE;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating several offsetted box shadows, you can just use one with no offset and a 5px spread radius :

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEE);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #EEE;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

More [info on box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `outline` instead of `box-shadow`. Both properties do not take up space.

```css
button {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #EEE);
    outline: 5px solid #EEE; /*this*/
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```